# how to add legend to scatterplot3d in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I would like to add legend to my scatterplot3d. I created 3 separate plot and overlay them into 1 plot so i don't know where the syntax for legend("topleft",inset=0.5)  should go

```
Plot <-scatterplot3d(data$Size,data$Pct,data$bias1, type='h', zlim=c(-20,100), xlab="size", ylab= "Percent", zlab="Bias")

Plot$points3d (data$Size,data$Pct,data$Bias2,
  col="blue", type="h", pch=15, cex=.6)  

Plot$points3d(data$Size,data$Pct,data$Bias3,
  col="red", type="h", pch=4, cex=.6)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the vignette? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterplot3d/vignettes/s3d.pdf

Comment: @ Roman:  Thank you.  The pdf is very helpful and I figured it out!!

Comment: Please post an example that solved your problem.

Answer (score 5):

It's an old question. But I had the same issue and solved it with the following code.
I have four timeseries with a duration of a year in a 3D plot.

As usual, I created the graphic like this:

```
s3d <- scatterplot3d(...)
```

And then just added the legend like this:

```
legend(s3d$xyz.convert(18, 0, 12), col= c("green","blue", "red", "black"), bg="white", lty=c(1,1), lwd=2, yjust=0, legend = c("2010", "2011", "2012", "Prognose für 2013"), cex = 1.1)
```